# How to terminate an Observable?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have an Observable that I want to terminate if a certain condition is not met (that is if the response from a certain website is unsuccessful), so that I can re-query the website, and call the observable again. How do I go about doing it?

Here's what I want to do:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

        //Perform network actions here

        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            //terminate this Observable so I can retrieve the token and call this observable again
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "terminate the Observable"? Do you mean that you want to contain all re-connection logic inside the observable? Do you want for your downstream subscribers to receive an event when you do terminate so they can resubscribe or do you just want to do it for them without their say/involvement.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [retry](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) operator of Rx. And need not to terminate an Observable.

Defined a custom exception:

```
public class FailedException extends RuntimeException{
    // ...
}


private static final int RETRY_COUNT = 3; // max retry counts
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            //Perform network actions here
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                // if response is unsucceed, invoke onError method and it will be stop emit data and into retry method.
                subscriber.onError(new FailedException());
            }
        }

    })
    .retry((integer, throwable) -> {
        // Retry network actions when failed.
        // if return true, Observable will be retry to network actions emit data;
        // if return false, you can process in onError() method of Subscribe.
        return throwable instanceof FailedException && integer < RETRY_COUNT;
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can filter the result before subscribing. Do not handle it when you create your observable.

Check observable.filter function

Comment: That's a useful operator. But what if it doesn't go through the filter? Does the Observable just stop? Because I do not want to proceed with the logic that's after my if loop. How would I do with a filter? Should I have the if loop's result as a filter check? And if it's false, then what?

Comment: It will stop the chain at the filter function from emitting more items (in other words yes, your subscribe method will not be called)