# RxJava How to properly Resubscribe onError

Tags: android, rx-java

So im working on an android project, and currently, i am using RxJava to fetch data from the WS and display it as soon as its ready. I'm using the following aproach, which i'm not sure is the best.

- If onError gets called, subscribe again

  ```
      private void getGeneralLiveData(Observable<CurrentGameInfo> obsCurrentGameInfoBySummonerId) {
      /**
       * Get General Live Data
       */
      subscriptions.add(
              obsCurrentGameInfoBySummonerId
                  .doOnSubscribe(() -> currentGameGlobalInfo.enableProgressBar(true))
                  .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> currentGameGlobalInfo.enableProgressBar(false))
                  .subscribe(onNext -> ... ,onError-> {
                          getGeneralLiveData(obsCurrentGameInfoBySummonerId);
                   }
  );
  ```

This is currently working, and i get the results i want. But i am not sure this is the best approach. So i have two questions:

- Is there any proper way of accomplish the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [retry](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html) operator, see this answer:

[How to terminate an Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989849/how-to-terminate-an-observable/32991235#32991235)

Comment: yes that is a good point, retry would work. It's my bad, i asked the wrong answer. I meant to ask the same answer, but in a context of chained observables. In that case, would retry be applied to the original observable (i mean the first observable in the chain), or just the last one?